# Any way to unlock T-Mobile ZTE V768?

Tags: sim-unlocking

A friend of mine purchased a ZTE V768 Concord from ZTE. It was not under any contract, but it is still locked to use any foreign SIM-card anyways.

We are far away from the US, so is there any way to unlock it?

I know those services like [this](http://www.unlocklocks.com/), but I don't think those could provide me an unlock code, can they?

So, any way to unlock it? Thank you!

Comment: Has the phone been purchased directly from T-Mobile while your friend was in the US, or via eBay or similar 3rd party?

Comment: It was purchased directly via T-Mobile. No eBay or similar used.

Comment: The online unlocking services should work in that case. Although it's not as secure as calling T-Mobile directly and requesting an unlock code.